# String not getting value from string in requete.cs

Tags: c#, string, null, entity

I am not getting value from a string.

Exemple :

```
public static void ticket(string ticketName) // ticketName = "testTicket"
{
   string abc = ticketName; // result : abc null
}
```

Can someone help me please I am stuck on it for almost 2 days

Here is real code

```
namespace FirstOutlookAddIn
```

{
    public partial class lblSubject : Form
    {
        Outlook._Explorer currentExplorer = null;

```
    private string Conversation_ID;
    private string subject;
    private string senderName;
    private string senderEmail;
    private string incident;
    private DateTime creationDate;


    public lblSubject()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Outlook.Application myAPP = new Outlook.Application();
    }



    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Outlook.Application myAPP = new Outlook.Application();

        Outlook.MAPIFolder selectedFolder =
            myAPP.Application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder;
        String expMessage = "Your current folder is "
            + selectedFolder.Name + ".\n";
        String itemMessage = "Item is unknown.";
        try
        {
            if (myAPP.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection.Count > 0)
            {
                Object selObject = myAPP.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
                if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
                {
                    Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                        (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
                    itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message : Entery ID:"+ mailItem.EntryID+ " Conversation ID" + mailItem.ConversationID;
                    Conversation_ID = mailItem.ConversationID;
                    //mailItem.Display(false);


                    // Grab the Body
                   //txtBody.Text = mailItem.Body;
                   rIncident.Text = mailItem.Body;
                   incident = mailItem.Body;
                   senderName = mailItem.SenderName;
                   senderEmail = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
                   creationDate = mailItem.CreationTime;
                   Conversation_ID = mailItem.ConversationID;
                    // Sender Name
                    lblSenderName.Text = mailItem.SenderName;
                    // Sender Email
                    lblSenderEmail.Text = mailItem.SenderEmailAddress;
                    // Creation date
                    lblCreationdate.Text = mailItem.CreationTime.ToString();
                }
    }



    private void lblSubject_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cboUsers.DataSource = Requetes.userliste();
        cboPriority.DataSource = Requetes.priorityliste();
    }



    private void btnCreateTicket_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userNom = cboUsers.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string priorityNom = cboPriority.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string convoID = Conversation_ID;

        Requetes.saveTicket(userNom, priorityNom, subject,
            senderName, senderEmail, incident, convoID, creationDate);

    }



}
```

}

//Requete Class

namespace FirstOutlookAddIn
{
    public static class Requetes
    {
        private static TicketingDBEntities6 ticketDB = new TicketingDBEntities6();
        private static DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

```
    //Recover User ID
        public static void saveTicket(string userNom2, string priority, string subject, 
            string senderName, string email, string incident, string conversationID, DateTime mailCreateTime)
        {

            User u = ticketDB.User.Single(user1 => user1.User_Nom == userNom2);
            int userIdenti = u.User_Id;

            Priority p = ticketDB.Priority.Single(pr => pr.Priority_Name == priority);
            int priorityID = p.Priority_Id;
            Ticket t = new Ticket();

            t.Ticket_Body = incident;
            t.Ticket_ConversationID = conversationID;
            t.Ticket_SenderEmail = email;
            t.Ticket_SentDate = mailCreateTime;
            t.Ticket_Priority = p.Priority_Id;



            ObjectSet<Ticket> insert = ticketDB.Ticket;
            insert.AddObject(t);
            ticketDB.SaveChanges();

          // Ticket ticket = ticketDB.Ticket.Single(ti => ti.Ticket_ConversationID == conversationID);



            string getConvoID;
            string getSenderEmail;
            getSenderEmail = email;
            DateTime dt = mailCreateTime;
            getConvoID = conversationID;

            var Users = (from uc in ticketDB.Ticket
                         where uc.Ticket_ConversationID == getConvoID
                         select uc
                         );

            int abc = Users.Count();


            Ticket_User tu = new Ticket_User();


            tu.Ticket_User_Ticket_Id = ticket.Ticket_Id;
            tu.Ticket_User_User_id = u.User_Id;

            ObjectSet<Ticket_User> insert_Ticket_User = ticketDB.Ticket_User;
            insert_Ticket_User.AddObject(tu);
            ticketDB.SaveChanges();



        }

}
```

}

THE PROBLEM IS WITH Classrequete

for exemple 
`if conversationID = "FFF1614651616fssd";t.Ticket_ConversationID = conversationID; // in debuget it shows conversationID is equal to "FF.....ssd" but t.Ticket_ConversationID is null`:(((((((
 `

Hope someone can help me out. Sorry for too much code code here

Comment: Have you stepped through this in the debugger?  My guess is that you think `ticketName` is equal to "testTicket" because that's what it's supposed to be, but because of a bug elsewhere, the value is actually null.

Comment: This is utterly impossible if your values are assigned as you have described.

Comment: Could you show more code?

Comment: Please provide us more details on your code :)

Comment: If the `ticketName` is null it means that the problem lies outside the code you posted.

Comment: Show how you declare your ticketName.

Comment: i tried to copy complete code between 2 classes. my "requete class is static which is connected with sqlexpress database.

Comment: I stopped reading after `button3_Click`. Seriously, please don't.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are trying to call ticket() method but you are not passing parameter to ticket("testTicket"), or when you try to call ticket(value) might be your variable is not getting value from source, I am very sure. everything is pretty straight forward.

Try to follow it:

```
public void SomeEvent()
{
   string value = "testTicket";
   ticket(value);
}

public static void ticket(string ticketName) // ticketName = "testTicket"
{
   string abc = ticketName; // result : abc null
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: i am getting value from source and i am able to store it in database but when i try to insert same value in a variable it shows null. I checked it in debuger

Comment: Please share some specific code block then it will be easy to sort out issue. Thanks

Comment: HI Jahan, thank you for your answer. Can i send you a part of my real code so you can better understand my problem ?

Comment: i am not able to post it before 90 mintues if possible can you please send send me a test message on randhawarulzATgmail so i can send u a copy there.

Comment: Hi I sent you an email with complete project and a print screen. Thanks alot for your help.